# AutoFac - Creating factories by enum with inheriting objects

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, factory

```
class Person : IParticipant {}
class Doctor: Person {}
class RandomParticipantGenerator : IParticipantGenerator{
    enum PersonType
    {
       Person,
       Doctor
    }
    public IParticipant GetParticipant(PersonType type, State state)
    {
    }
    public List<IParticipant> GetParticipants(PersonType type, State state, int numOfPeople)
    {
    }
}
```

I have these classes in my program, I need to be able to produce `Person`/`Doctor` with the `GetParticipant` method. It should return a `Docter` When the `PersonType` enum is `Doctor` a new `Person` when the provided type is equal to `Person`.
I am using a simple factory method but I want to implement this using **Autofac**.

I would love to get some help on the matter.

Comment: Could you share what you tried so far ?

Comment: Until now i didn't use autofac. i just returned new Person if type was person. Now what i wouls like to happen is autofac giving me the chosen implementation depending on the type, and i have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Autofac in ASP.NET Core, firstly you should configure the `CreateHostBuilder` method to use "Autofac" as IoC Container.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Then you should add `ConfigureContainer` method in the `Startup` class to provide a custom configuration to the container builder as follow:

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Register<IParticipant>((context, parameter) =>
    {
        var type = parameter.TypedAs<PersonType>();
        return type switch
        {
            PersonType.Person => new Person(),
            PersonType.Doctor => new Doctor(),
            _ => new Person(),// Or throw an exception
        };
    }).As<IParticipant>();
}
```

Finally use `Func<PersonType, IParticipant>` instead of `IParticipant` for `_participantFactory` declaration and inject it like this:

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    private readonly Func<PersonType, IParticipant> _participantFactory;

    public SampleController (Func<PersonType, IParticipant> participantFactory)
    {
        _participantFactory = participantFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var participant = _participantFactory(PersonType.Person);
        return Ok(participant );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm already doing something like this. I want to use autofac to get the implementation.